# usage: py [-x] [-l] [-c PRE_CMD] [-C POST_CMD] [-V] [-h] [expression]

Tags: django

i get this error when ever i do anything

[image]

I just installed Ubuntu and now i cant run any of my django project.
is it some problem with my python/django version ?

Answer (score 1):

You are entering `py manage.py runserver` which gives you the error

> py:error: unrecognized arguments: runserver

because you have to enter `python manage.py runserver`.